# SwiftUI: Using FocusState in NavigationView doesn't dismiss the keyboard properly

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-navigationstack

While implementing a SwiftUI only application I'm using NavigationView for iOS 15 / NavigationStack for iOS 16, Keyboard doesn't dismiss properly under different conditions

- When using NavigationView + FocusState and running on iOS 15 phone it works as expected,
  The behavior can be seen here: https://www.loom.com/share/c716f2ed841645a5a7ea4fee54587c4f

  - You can see that the keyboard dismisses successfully and the ScrollView claims back its bottom safeAreaInset
- When using NavigationStack / NavigationView + FocusState and running on iOS 16 phone, it doesn't work, The behavior can be seen here: https://www.loom.com/share/cd3c619522194ef8aa5d14a44095a585

  - You can see that the keyboard dismisses successfully but the ScrollView does not claim back its bottom safeAreaInset unless interacted with
- When using NavigationStack / NavigationView + FocusState + CocoaScrollView from SwiftUIX and running on iOS 16 phone, it works as expected, The behavior can be seen here: https://www.loom.com/share/8035e3bd1c134e0587e4342e98aa6b9c

  - You can see that the keyboard dismisses successfully and the ScrollVIew claims back its bottom safeAreaInsets
- When using NavigationView + FocusState + CocoaScrollView from SwiftUIX and running on iOS 15 phone, it works as expected, but updating FocusState doesn't refresh the view at all it's as if the FocusState doesn't effect the view only if the View that contains the FocusState is pushed from another screen, The behavior can be seen here: https://www.loom.com/share/a9d218012e434ee49eb02d62092db4e3

  - The video shows when the View is pushed from NavigationLink inside NavigationView it doesn't work at all, but when it's the root view it works just fine
  - Also if we use ScrollView normally and it's pushed using NavigationLink it still works fine.

Code in question

**NavigationView + FocusState running on iOS 15:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    
    enum Field: FocusField, CaseIterable {
        case firstName
    }
    
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                Color.green.opacity(0.2)
                    .frame(height: 250)
                    .padding(.top, 200)
                
                VStack {
                    TextField("", text: $text, prompt: Text("Input"))
                        .focused($focusedField, equals: .firstName)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .padding()
                    
                    Button("Unfocus", action: {
                        focusedField = nil
                    })
                    
                }
                .background { Color.red }
            }
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(.light)
    }
}
```

**NavigationStack + FocusState running on iOS 16:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    
    enum Field: FocusField, CaseIterable {
        case firstName
    }
    
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                Color.green.opacity(0.2)
                    .frame(height: 250)
                    .padding(.top, 200)
                
                VStack {
                    TextField("", text: $text, prompt: Text("Input"))
                        .focused($focusedField, equals: .firstName)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .padding()
                    
                    Button("Unfocus", action: {
                        focusedField = nil
                    })
                    
                }
                .background { Color.red }
            }
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(.light)
    }
}
```

**NavigationStack + FocusState + CocoaScrollView running on iOS 16:**

```
import SwiftUIX

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    
    enum Field: FocusField, CaseIterable {
        case firstName
    }
    
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            CocoaScrollView {
                Color.green.opacity(0.2)
                    .frame(height: 250)
                    .padding(.top, 200)
                
                VStack {
                    TextField("", text: $text, prompt: Text("Input"))
                        .focused($focusedField, equals: .firstName)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .padding()
                    
                    Button("Unfocus", action: {
                        focusedField = nil
                    })
                    
                }
                .background { Color.red }
            }
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(.light)
    }
}
```

**NavigationView + FocusState + CocoaScrollView running on iOS 15:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    
    enum Field: FocusField, CaseIterable {
        case firstName
        case lastName
        case username
    }
    
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Next Page") {
                CocoaScrollView {
                    Color.green.opacity(0.2)
                        .frame(height: 250)
                        .padding(.top, 200)
                    
                    VStack {
                        TextField("", text: $text, prompt: Text("Input"))
                            .focused($focusedField, equals: .firstName)
                            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                            .padding()
                        
                        TextField("", text: $text, prompt: Text("Input"))
                            .focused($focusedField, equals: .lastName)
                            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                            .padding()
                        
                        TextField("", text: $text, prompt: Text("Input"))
                            .focused($focusedField, equals: .username)
                            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                            .padding()
                        
                        Button("Next Field", action: {
                            focusedField = focusedField?.next
                        })
                        
                    }
                    .background { Color.red }
                }
            }
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(.light)
    }
}
```

What I ended up doing is creating a `CustomScrollView` struct that wraps this logic so that it's compatible with iOS 15 / iOS 16

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUIX

struct CustomScrollView<Content: View>: View {
    
    private let axes: Axis.Set
    private let showsIndicators: Bool
    private let content: () -> Content
    
    init(
        axes: Axis.Set = .vertical,
        showsIndicators: Bool,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self.axes = axes
        self.showsIndicators = showsIndicators
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            CocoaScrollView(axes, showsIndicators: showsIndicators, content: content)
                .alwaysBounceVertical(true)
        } else {
            SwiftUI.ScrollView(axes, showsIndicators: showsIndicators, content: content)
        }
    }
}
```

Which kind of works fine, but that's pretty much tacky and can break in any iOS version.

Any ideas would be appreciated